# Most user friendly way to organise this content?

Tags: theming, nodes

We're trying to work out how best to organise this content: https://international.permaculture.org.uk/for-organisations

It should be one column layout but with text and image aligned next to each other which will then be responsive (i.e. image moves to below paragraph associated with it)

It was suggested that the responsiveness could be detailed in within the text editor source for each pane, by giving the text and image separate div tags and assigning them some css, but I think the administrators who are going to use these sites would not feel happy with that approach.

I am wondering if using Nodequeue module is a good idea? Or if there is another way? Content order needs to be felxible so I don't think using a view is best way.

Comment: Have you considered using the Paragraphs module (https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs)? With it you can compose content from units, so you can have blocks of text as one paragraph type and image plus caption as another. Editors can intersperse them at will.

We have used it very successfully to build responsive layouts. eg. https://www.rcplondon.ac.uk/news/most-pleasant-cooling-liquor-hans-sloane-and-coconuts

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [Bootstrap 3 theme/module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) it is very easy to install and use, and has built-in responsiveness to mobile vs laptop screens, which automatically moves your images below text, changes your menu to the mobile menu button, and other nifty features. You can copy its subtheme and make it into your own custom theme and there change many of the vanilla styles as well, so its very customizable.